# Hacer animacion de colores en un titulo

Tags: jquery-ui

Requiero hacerle  a un título una animación que cambie de color después de determinado tiempo, posteriormente vuelva al color original, y permanezca cambiando entre dos colores indefinidamente.

Comment: Hola Camilo, bienvenido a Stackoverflow en Español. Verás, esta comunidad es diferente a los foros que tal vez conozcas. Aquí resolvemos problemas __específicos__ de programación. Si no sabes por donde empezar, lo mejor que puedes hacer es usar Google. Te invito a que visites el [tour] para conozcas un poco de como funcionamos.

Comment: También te será de ayuda consultar la guía [Cómo preguntar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Además de jQuery, necesitas añadir jQueryUI a tu web en el head o añadir esta librería para animar colores:

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.color-animation/1/mainfile"></script>
```

Luego en JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  animateForever();
});

function animateForever()
{
  var div = $('h1');
  var color1 = '#A333FF';
  var color2 = '#3BD6C6';

  div.animate({color: color1}, 1000, function()
  {
    div.animate({color: color2}, 1000, function()
    {
      animateForever();
    });
  });
}
```

Te dejo un Plunker para que lo veas: https://embed.plnkr.co/tT16f9bxrLze5RiMQB4l/

Comment: Gracias por tu colaboración. Es justo lo que andaba buscando. No tenía ni idea de cómo hacerlo